# Is there any way to prevent the program from termination if an exception was thrown before a child thread had been joined?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

```
//...
try
{
    std::thread someThread(someFunc, someArg); // assume it doesn't throw
    foo(); // might throw
    bar(); // might throw
    someThread.join();
}
//...
```

In the above example, if either `foo()` or `bar()` throws, `someThread`'s destructor will call the `terminate()` function because `someThread` had not been joined to the parent thread due to stack unwinding, that will lead to termination of the entire program. Is there any way to prevent this behavior and handle the exception without killing the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to simply declare `someThread` before the try/catch block and use move-assignment in the `try` clause.  Then call to `join` can then be immediately after the `catch` clause...

```
std::thread someThread;
try
{
    someThread = std::thread(someFunc, someArg);
    foo(); // might throw
    bar(); // might throw
}
catch (...) {

    /*
     * Do some error handling...
     */
}
if (someThread.joinable())
    someThread.join();
```

Alternatively, if your compiler supports `c++20` youmight want to look at [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `std::jthread` is exactly what I need.